# How important is equally leveling characters in Ch. 5 onward?

Tags: disgaea-3

I am at the 3rd battle of chapter 5, and most of my characters are levels 28 to 31. I've been doing a good job of keeping all of my characters at roughly the same level, but thanks to the 4 story characters that were added recently (Sapphire, Raspberyl, Asuka, Kyoko), it's become far more tedious to do that, and I'm wondering how concerned I should be with having only a handful of highly-leveled characters. My main concern is that if if I spend a lot of time leveling the story characters, I'll end up in a battle where I cannot use them or that if I don't level them, I'll end up in a battle where I'm forced to use them at which point they may be too weak; that's something that's bitten me while playing the various Fire Emblem games, and I'm wondering if that's something I need to concern myself with in Disgaea or if I can safely level the characters I prefer to use regardless of whether or not they're story characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that important. You can bring ten characters out onto a map and you choose any characters you want. I don't think the game ever forces you to use certain characters, but it's been a long time since I've played Disgaea 3. Levelling up characters that are behind is also pretty easy. Just go through the item world or maybe replay a few levels, use your more powerful characters to clear the level and bring out your lower level characters just to watch. If you see bonus XP awards on the bonus gauge, build it up with combos and/or clearing all the geo panels in one big chain.

A problem you might run into is that I don't think you can get enough XP from just from completing the story levels to beat the last fewlevels. That's a general problem with the Disgaea games, the expectation is that you'll be spending some time levelling the item world or class word.

Answer (score 0):

*note: I haven't played Disgaea 3 but have played Disgaea 1, 2 and 4. This question seems to be relevant to all of them.*

The most effective way of making your characters stronger is giving them better equipment. Since any class can wear any type of equipment (with the exception of monster weapons) you can easily transfer strong weapons of a high level character to a low level character. The low level character will obviously not be as strong but will not be that much of a burden with the right gear. Low level characters level very fast (They can level hundreds of levels by defeating one enemy or even for just being included in a team attack).

I have the habit of making A LOT of characters. Many of them happen to be underleveled obviously while some get incredibly powerful. The low level characters catch up quickly with good gear.

Just use whichever characters you like most. Normally the story in Disgaea is fairly easy and you can get away with underleveled characters.